# Trignometry Building Problem

Tags: trigonometry, recreational-mathematics

Ok guys this is one of the trig recrational problems i was doing and i cant seem to draw the problem right... Please help..

A surveryor standing 69 meters from the base of the bulding measures the angule to the top of the bulding and finds it to be 35degrees. The surveyerour then mesaures the angle to the top of the radio tower on the bulding and finds that it is 46degrees. How tall is the radio tower.

I got to the point i got the hieght of the bulding. But have no idea what so ever to get the hieght of the radio tower please help.

Comment: Well if you can get the height of the whole thing, then the height of the tower is just the difference.

Comment: Thats the problem @Jedediyah i didnt get the height of the whole thing. Just the blding. The radio tower if the taller one... I think

Comment: ah ok.  Well how did you get the height of the building?  You can do something very similar but with the different angle.

Comment: Yes i did but im not sure at all if it is the correct height. I really need help with this @Jedediyah

Comment: The radio tower is on top of the building. You should assume that the radio tower is also 69 meters from the surveyor (distance measured horizontally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got the height $h$ of the building with 
$$
\tan(35^\circ) = \frac{h}{69}
$$
You can get the height $H$ of the whole thing similarly, with
$$
\tan(46^\circ) = \frac{H}{69}
$$
Then the tower height is just the difference $H-h$.

Comment: Suprisingly i actually got the correct height of the bulding! Horray!!

Comment: Wait isnt the tower hieght the hieght of the whole thing Jed?

Comment: It sounds to me like there is a radio tower on top of a building.  The height of the tower is the height while it is on top of the building, but observed from the same location.  Two triangles where one side is taller for one.

Comment: Ok Jed Thank you so much. Your a big help!